# Align text just left of a button, which is placed on the right side of the page

Tags: html, css

How do I align a text just to the left of a button, that is placed on the right side of the page, independent of the text size? I'm using an absolute position right now, but that's probably not a very good solution.

```
<nav class="someLine">
    <button type="button" class="back">Back</button>
    <text class="errorMsg">I'm an error!</text>
    <button type="button" class="continue">Continue</button>
</nav>

.errorMsg {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 120px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.someLine {
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.continue, #btnAddProduct {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h959khth/

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Why does absolute positioning not seem to be a good solution solution for you? It works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could float both elements using

```
float: right;
```

Then they'll hug the right edge of their parent div no matter how it gets sized.

If you float them make sure you have an element after them with

```
float: clear;
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this sweets your need :

```
.errorMsg {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 10px;
    right: 120px;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
    left: 4%
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h959khth/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `float` [prop](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) instead of `position:absolute;`. To achieve what you want with floated elements you need to set `position` att to `relative`. See the demo:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h959khth/14/)